# Kendo UI - How to localize tooltip of spin boxes in NumericTextbox control?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

How to localize/change the text of tooltip of spin boxes in Kendo UI NumericTextbox control?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've had the same problem. For some reason the "kendo.messages.xx-XX.js" localization files don't localize the two messages on the spin buttons, but I've found a way to do that:

```
if (kendo.ui.NumericTextBox) {
    kendo.ui.NumericTextBox.prototype.options =
    $.extend(true, kendo.ui.NumericTextBox.prototype.options,{
      "upArrowText": "Increase value",
      "downArrowText": "Decrease value"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To localize the text you have to simply include the corresponding messages script after the kendo include. The `script` and `link` are taken from [Kendos documentation on localization](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/localization/overview#configuration-Set):

For example:

```js
$("#numeric").kendoNumericTextBox();
```

```html
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<!-- This is the important line, you may need to change de-DE to your desired locale -->
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/messages/kendo.messages.de-DE.min.js"></script>

<p>Hover over the up or down caret to see the german texts:</p>
<input id="numeric" type="number" title="numeric" value="17" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
```

You might want to check the available localization files in the [`kendo-ui-core` repository](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/tree/master/src/messages) or their docs.

Note that this is [how the messages script does it](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/2018.1.221/src/messages/kendo.messages.en-US.js#L406-L414) (which is already shown in the other answer):

```
/* NumericTextBox messages */

if (kendo.ui.NumericTextBox) {
  kendo.ui.NumericTextBox.prototype.options =
  $.extend(true, kendo.ui.NumericTextBox.prototype.options,{
    "upArrowText": "Increase value",
    "downArrowText": "Decrease value"
  });
}
```

So you should be able to customize these texts yourself if you want.